# What is the best way to switch between different ranges when designing a multimeter using microcontroller?

Tags: pic, switches, multimeter

We are developing a multimeter using a PIC18 microcontroller and we are searching for the best method to switch between different ranges in multimeter with the smallest possible amount of switching delay.

Comment: Are you using a manual switch to select ranges or is this done automatically i.e. is it intended to be an auto-ranging multimeter? What sort of accuracy are you looking for?

Answer (score 3):

You don't give a number for the maximum delay you require, or much description of the design, but I'm assuming it's to be an autoranging/switching type of meter.

There are plenty of cheap analogue multplexers available, the best known being the 74xx4051, 4052 and 4053 series.
These are dual polarity 8:1 (4051), 2 x 4:1 (4052), and 4 x 2:1 (4053) muxes, available for under 50 cents and made by various manufacturers (e.g. TI, AD, Maxim, etc) I would have a look at these and similar offerings. Here is an [example 4051 part](http://uk.farnell.com/on-semiconductor/mc74hc4051adtg/ic-analog-mux-dmux-8-x-1-tssop/dp/1705881) from Farnell (many more [here](http://uk.farnell.com/jsp/search/browse.jsp?N=202451&Ns=P_PRICE_FARNELL_UK%7C0&locale=en_UK&appliedparametrics=true&getResults=true&suppressRedirect=true&isRedirect=&originalQueryURL=/jsp/search/browse.jsp?N=202451&No=0&getResults=true&appliedparametrics=true&locale=en_UK&divisionLocale=en_UK&catalogId=&skipManufacturer=false&skipParametricAttributeId=&prevNValues=202451)). Also see [analogue switches](http://uk.farnell.com/jsp/search/browse.jsp?N=202450&No=0&getResults=true&appliedparametrics=true&locale=en_UK&divisionLocale=en_UK&catalogId=&skipManufacturer=false&skipParametricAttributeId=&prevNValues=202450&filtersHidden=false&appliedHidden=false&autoApply=false&originalQueryURL=/jsp/search/browse.jsp?N=202450&No=0&getResults=true&appliedparametrics=true&locale=en_UK&divisionLocale=en_UK&catalogId=&skipManufacturer=false&skipParametricAttributeId=&prevNValues=202450).

For slower switching only one or two ways, but better isolation and lower resistance there are mechanical relays (or solid state relays, such as the [PhotoMOS type](http://uk.farnell.com/clare/cpc1008n/relay-solid-state-contacts/dp/1653755) from Clare) These can be used where appropriate, together with IC switches, e.g. to isolate one channel from the next when active.

Answer (score 1):

For a lot of applications nowadays, you can use a single high resolution delta-sigma A/D and not bother with ranging at all.  The tradeoff to get the high resolution is long conversion times, but in a multimeter time is measured on a human scale so a few 10s of ms is still instantaneous.

Another trick is to present the input signal with different gains to the different A/D inputs of the micro.  The micro then uses the one with the highest reading that isn't saturated.  Usually you do a little blending with the next lower reading down so that there isn't a sudden jump when different ranges are used.  It also helps to do some calibration during manufacturing to store offsets and gains separately for each of the A/D inputs.

Comment: "to the different A/D inputs of the micro"  This is usually just a multiplexer to a single ADC anyway.  Might as well use the internal one instead of building one externally.